Get the number of elements from a string stored in a variable with delimiter between them
I want to get the number of elements from a string stored in a variable with delimiter between them.
Nb: I have the mystring variable that has a specific format that I need to keep as it is.
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM This is what I try to make working :

set mystring=0510150^\^|0510298^\^|051072803^\^|0510966
for /f "tokens=* delims=|" %%a in ("%mystring%") do (set /A nbfields=%nbfields%+1)
echo The number of elements is : %nbfields%

REM The following is a simplified version I used for debugging but it doesn't work too :

set mystring=0510150A0510298A051072803A0510966
for /f "tokens=1 delims=A" %%a in %mystring% do (set /A nbfields=%nbfields%+1)
echo The number of elements is : %nbfields%

I want to do this count in less than 5 windows batch lines, or with a single line powershell call from a windows batch file.
I must run this "count" inside a windows batch file, but it can contains 1 or 2 lines of powershell call if it is necessary.
I've found several samples using  cmd on this website but I can't adapt them to my problem...

Use set "mystring=0510150 0510298 051072803 0510966" or set "mystring=0510150,0510298,051072803,0510966" or set "mystring=0510150;0510298;051072803;0510966" and next for %%I in (%mystring%) do set /A nbfields+=1. A FOR /F loop cannot be used to get the number of tokens (strings separated by normal space, comma, semicolon or an OEM encoded no-break space with decimal byte value 255).

You could accomplish this with a FOR /F but requires a lot of extra code.  Essentially you do string replacement on the string to change the PIPE to a LINEFEED.  We have it documented on DosTips.com somewhere.  Still looking for that thread.

This technique comes from a thread on DosTips.com
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "mystring=0510150^\^|0510298^\^|051072803^\^|0510966"
set i=1
set "mystring!i!=%mystring:|=" & set /A i+=1 & set "mystring!i!=%"
echo Fields=%i%

Another option is to keep splitting the string apart and looping back to the FOR /F command.
@echo off
set "mystring=0510150^\^|0510298^\^|051072803^\^|0510966"
set i=0    
:Loop
for /f "tokens=1* delims=|" %%A in ("%mystring%") do (set /A "i+=1" &set "mystring=%%B")
if "%mystring%"=="" (echo fields=%i%) else (goto Loop)

And here is the crazy idea from DosTips.com that replaces a delimiter with a linefeed so that the FOR /f command treats each field as a line.
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "mystring=0510150^\^|0510298^\^|051072803^\^|0510966"
set i=0
for /F "delims=" %%a in (^"!mystring:^|^=^
% Do NOT remove this line %
!^") do (
  set /a i+=1
)
echo Fields=%i%


My approach would be
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

set "mystring=0510150^\^|0510298^\^|051072803^\^|0510966"
SET "newstring=%mystring:|=","%"&SET /a nbfields=0
FOR %%c IN ("%newstring%") do SET /a nbfields+=1
echo The number of elements is : %nbfields%

echo testing with a different string...

set "mystring=051,0150^\^|051 0298^\^|0510, ,72803^\^|0510966"
SET "newstring=%mystring:|=","%"&SET /a nbfields=0
FOR %%c IN ("%newstring%") do SET /a nbfields+=1
echo The number of elements is : %nbfields%

GOTO :EOF

That is, simply replacing each delimiter with ",", then enclosing the resulting string in quotes and counting the results.
Note that in your original code,nbfields=%nbfields%+1 would substitute the value that nbfields had on encountering the for for %nbfields% - the old favourite Variables are not behaving as expected
